# Checking if two files have the same content not working

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I have a script that iterates through all the files in a directory and checks whether the files contain the same content or not with any other files in the same directory:

```
Check() 
{
    if [ -e "new.txt" ]
    then
        rm new.txt
    fi
    for item in "$2"/*
    do
        if [ ! -d "$item" ]
        then
            diff "$1" "$item">new.txt
            if [ -s "new.txt" ]
            then
                echo "$1 $item"
                echo "Yes"
            fi
        fi
    done
}

Iterate()
{
    for item in "$2"/*
    do
        if [ ! -d "$item" ]
        then
            Check $item $2
        fi
    done
}

Iterate $1 $2
```

And the bash

```
bash script.sh asd /home/ljuben
```

However when I run the script it always echoes "Yes" eve if the files don't contain the same content.

And ideas?

Comment: @Jesse_b I don't think that's quite true; unless the `-s` option is given, `diff` will produce an *empty* file if the files are the same: however `[ -s "new.txt" ]` will return true if `new.txt` exists and is **not** empty (inverting the OP's intended logic)

Comment: Regardless, as @Jesse_b and @Kusalananda have pointed out, it would be simpler and better practice to check the exit status of your comparison command rather than creating and testing a file: e.g. `if ! cmp -s "$1" "$item"; then echo "Different"; fi`

Comment: What is `asd` on your command line and why don't you use that argument in your script?

Comment: It's nothing. I started it because I thought it must be made with two arguments but then I realized that I can make it with one

Answer (score 2):

Your script seems to not use its first argument.  It is passed to the `Iterate` function, and then never seen again.

But the real issue is that you run `diff` on every combination of two files, and then look at the size of the diff.  The size of the diff will be non-zero for files that are different.  Your script is therefore reporting `Yes` for every combination of files that are *different*, not the same.

You also needlessly run the diff between file `A` and `B` twice (`A` vs. `B` and then later `B` vs. `A`).  You can get by this by generating the file list only once, and then iterating over that.

Alternative script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    printf 'Usage: %s directory\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# set positional parameters to the list of files in the given directory
set -- "$1"/*

# while there's still files to process...
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    # skip over non-regular files
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        shift
        continue
    fi

    # now process the first item in the list against the other ones
    item=$1

    # shift off the first item from the list
    shift

    # loop over the remaining items...
    for name do
        # we're still not interested in non-regular files
        [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue

        # if they are the same, report this
        if cmp -s "$item" "$name"; then
            printf '%s and %s has same content\n' "$item" "$name"
        fi
    done
done
```

You may still have your two functions if you wish:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
    printf 'Usage: %s directory\n' "$0" >&2
    exit 1
fi

check () {
    # now process the first item in the list against the other ones
    item=$1

    # shift off the first item from the list
    shift

    # loop over the remaining items...
    for name do
        # we're still not interested in non-regular files
        [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue

        # if they are the same, report this
        if cmp -s "$item" "$name"; then
            printf '%s and %s has same content\n' "$item" "$name"
        fi
    done
}

iterate () {
    # set positional parameters to the list of files in the given directory
    set -- "$1"/*

    # while there's still files to process...
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        # only process regular files
        if [ -f "$1" ]; then
            check "$@" # checks the first item against the rest
        fi
        shift # get rid of the first item
    done
}

iterate "$1"
```

Notice how we don't let the `check` function generate its own file list.  Instead we pass the list of files to it.

For the lazy:

```
fdupes -1 /some/directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `diff` with the `-s` option:

> -s, --report-identical-files
>
> report when two files are the same

You also don't need to create a file with the output, you can just test on the exit of the `diff` command:

```
Check() 
{
    if [ -e "new.txt" ]
    then
        rm new.txt
    fi
    for item in "$2"/*
    do
        if [ ! -d "$item" ]
        then 
            if diff -s "$1" "$item"
            then
                echo "$1 $item"
                echo "Yes"
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

As Kusalananda pointed out `cmp` is probably a better option and is more portable.  You could use:

```
if cmp -s "$1" "$item"
then
    echo "$1 $item"
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

Comment: See also `cmp -s`  which is more portable.

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work

Comment: "Still doesn't work" doesn't help much.  What about it doesn't work?